# Translating URI in Kohana

Tags: localization, internationalization, routes, uri, kohana

How can I translate whole URI in routes using I18n?

Example:
(CZ URI => EN controller and action)

`http://example.com/clanky/pridat`

So i need to translate URI get name of controller and action:

`'clanky' => 'pridat',
'pridat' => 'add'`

// I'm sorry about my english :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kohana flexilang module does what you want: https://github.com/creatoro/flexilang

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am searching for.